# how to view the rails 4.1 app logs on linode server deployed with capistrano, unicorn, nginx and postgresql

Tags: logging, nginx, capistrano, unicorn, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I deploy a rails 4.1 app on linode server following the instruction on [rubytreesoftware.com](http://www.rubytreesoftware.com/resources/ruby-on-rails-41-ubuntu-1404-server-deployment). I didn't get any errors during the deployment but I'm getting the 500 error when I visit the site. I tried precompiling the assets and setting the asset precompile to true in the production environment but that too did't solve the problem. running the app in production locally works. Is there a way to view the logs on the server?

Answer (score 0):

1. ssh to your linode server (ex: ssh root@your_linode_ip)
2. cd into your current application folder and you will find a folder named log
3. cd into log folder and you will find a file named production.log (your_application_folder/log/production.log)
4. execute `tail production.log -n 100`. This command will print the last 100 lines logs.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, you can try to use `capistrano-logger` gem.

Add to Gemfile:

```
gem 'capistrano-logger', group: :development
```

Require in `Capfile`:

```
require 'capistrano/logger'
```

And then you can run:

```
$ bundle exec cap production logger:show
```